# Human body shape detection on image from Android device camera

Tags: android, android-camera, augmented-reality

I must implement an applcation that draws a heart on a person seen via an Android device camera(augmented reality stuff).

So, I must detect the shape/contour of the upper part of human body(head, neck, shoulders) in order to know where the heart must be situated. This stuff must be made in real time.

I've searched about this stuff but I haven't find something useful. Does anybody know some tutorials or examples of something related to this? Thanks.

Comment: Trying to detect a human body is a computer vision problem, and there is no easy answer. If you want to try though, you should look at [openCV for Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html), a library for feature selection and stuff. From there, I recommend assembling a research team of phDs, and start collecting models while we wait for phone hardware to support robust feature selection at 30 fps. 

[Relevant](http://xkcd.com/1425/)

Comment: so this is a job for a team of phDs?

Comment: Not necessarily, but this isn't a programming problem as much as it is an computer science problem. There is no easy way to make a computer recognize 'things', especially in real time. Using opencv, you might be able to get a mild success rate, but it will get harder and harder to get a high recognition without many false positives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using OpenCV if the memory isn't a problem ( your app would be like 50 MB). There are plenty of tutorials to learn how to use OpenCV. Try [Cascade Classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html)

In case of face detection, as far as i know, android has a library for this. [Camera.Face](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html)

Comment: I see that your example is about face recognition, but can it be adapted to recognize head and shoulders' outline? Because their outline will not be a simple form, linke a circle in this example